# Golang middleware with just the standard library

Tags: go

My first stackoverflow question, so please go easy on my naivety about stackoverflow and the question asked, beginner in golang.

I would like to know the difference between the two calls and also simple understanding of the `Handle`, `Handler`, `HandleFunc`, `HandlerFunc`.

> http.Handle("/profile", Logger(profilefunc))
>   http.HandleFunc("/", HomeFunc)

```
func main() {            
   fmt.Println("Starting the server.")

   profilefunc := http.HandlerFunc(ProfileFunc)

   http.Handle("/profile", Logger(profilefunc))
   http.HandleFunc("/", HomeFunc)

   http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:8081", nil)
}

func Logger(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        log.Println("Before serving request")
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        log.Println("After serving request")
    })
}

func ProfileFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "You are on the profile page.")
}

func HomeFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello Imran Pochi")
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@matryer/the-http-handler-wrapper-technique-in-golang-updated-bc7fbcffa702

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like ... simple understanding of the Handle, Handler, HandleFunc, HandlerFunc.

- `Handler` is an interface that can respond to an HTTP request and has a `ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)` method.
- `http.Handle` registers a `Handler` to handle HTTP requests matching a given `pattern`.
- `http.HandleFunc` registers a handler function to handle HTTP requests matching a given `pattern`. The handler function should be of the form `func(ResponseWriter, *Request)`.
- `HandlerFunc` is an explicit function type of the form `func(ResponseWriter, *Request)`. `HandlerFunc` has a method `ServeHTTP` that calls itself . This allows you to cast a function to a `HandlerFunc` and use it as a `Handler`.

> I would to know the difference between the two calls

```
http.Handle("/profile", Logger(profilefunc))
http.HandleFunc("/", HomeFunc)
```

`Logger` is an example of a [middleware](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/making-and-using-middleware), which is a function that takes an `http.Handler` and it returns another `http.Handler` that wraps the original handler. When called this handler may (or may not) call the nested `http.Handler` before and/or after performing some operation. So the first line is saying register the `profileFunc` `Handler` wrapped in the `Logger` middleware with the pattern "/profile". The second line is saying register the `HomeFunc` function with the "/" pattern.

Answer (score 2):

According to what I've seen from the Go documentation examples:

- A *Handler* is a type created to respond to an HTTP request. To make a type a Handler all one has to do is implement a `ServeHTTP()` method. The ServeHTTP() method does the actual request processing.
- `Handle()` takes the route and a Handler, the type that has an instance method named `ServeHttp()`. Note that it just takes the type, there's no need for one to point at the actual method/function that handles the request explicitly.
- `HandlerFunc` is a type that internally implements a `ServeHTTP()` method. `HandlerFunc` is used to cast any Go function, with the right signature, to a `HandlerFunc`. The newly minted `HandlerFunc` is then passed to the `Handle()` method together with the route it processes.
  Note that the `HandlerFunc` lets one implement request handlers by just writing functions without the need for a dedicated handler type.
- `HandleFunc()` takes a route and any function that has the right signature. `HandleFunc` is shorthand for first of all doing the type casting and then passing the function to the `Handle()` method.

The signature for a request handling function is:

```
  func handlerName(wr http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request)
```