# goji/httpauth - Cannot use with the standard Golang 'net/http' library

Tags: go, goji

The code

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "github.com/goji/httpauth"
)


func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

        data := "TEST"

        w.Header().Set("Content-Length", fmt.Sprint(len(data)))
        fmt.Fprint(w, string(data))
}

func main() {
        r:=http.HandlerFunc(rootHandler)
        http.HandleFunc("/", httpauth.SimpleBasicAuth("dave", "somepassword")(r))
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

returns

```
:!go build test.go
# command-line-arguments
./test.go:23:71: cannot use httpauth.SimpleBasicAuth("dave", "somepassword")(r) (type http.Handler) as type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in argument to http.HandleFunc
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to Go and don't understand why the example [here](https://github.com/goji/httpauth#nethttp) is incomplete and doesn't include a `YourHandler` function.

Comment: Aside: `w.Header().Set()` after `w.WriteHeader()` has no effect. Just in case that's also in your real program.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after much banging my head against the proverbial wall.

Use `http.Handle`, not `http.HandleFunc`! :)

So with the `main` function as

```
func main() {
        r:=http.HandlerFunc(rootHandler)
        http.Handle("/", httpauth.SimpleBasicAuth("dave", "somepassword")(r))
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

You have a complete working example of httpauth with net/http!

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110834/golang-middleware-with-just-the-standard-library?rq=1) has a really great overview of the inner workings as well.